# jqGrid does not expand to fit scrollable table content

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I'm debugging a code having jqGrid component. it is used to display project hierarchy. It has a div container with fixed width of 400px. In the generated HTML for jqGrid, table also has fixed width of 400px. (probably) due to this, when the tree expands horizontally, scroll bar appears but the grid does not expand to accommodate table contents. Hence, some of the table text goes beyond the grid boundaries. please refer to attached image.

I'm being a newbie here, it doesn't allow me to post images unfortunately :( (I'm not sufficiently 'reputed'!!)

thanks in advance!

Here's the generated HTML (I've removed some of the tds with 'display:none' to fit the post within character limit :

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="gbox_gridProject" dir="ltr" style="width: 400px;">
<div class="ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay" id="lui_gridProject"></div>
<div class="loading ui-state-default ui-state-active" id="load_gridProject">Loading...</div>
<div class="ui-jqgrid-view" id="gview_gridProject" style="width: 400px;">
<div class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-jqgrid-caption ui-widget-header ui-corner-top ui-helper-clearfix"><a role="link" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close ui-corner-all HeaderButton" style="right: 0px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span></a><span class="ui-jqgrid-title">List of Projects</span></div>
<div class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv" style="width: 400px;">
<div class="ui-jqgrid-hbox">
<table class="ui-jqgrid-htable" style="width:400px" role="grid" aria-labelledby="gbox_gridProject" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><thead>
<tr class="ui-jqgrid-labels" role="rowheader"><th id="gridProject_id" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 1px; display: none;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv" style="height: auto; width: 400px;">
<div style="position:relative;"><div></div>
<table id="gridProject" tabindex="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_gridProject" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" style="width: 400px;"><tbody>
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto">
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:400px;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1px;display:none;"></td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="utCQPQnEMSgWuMoWP" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="utCQPQnEMSgWuMoWP" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">utCQPQnEMSgWuMoWP</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="Root" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:18px;">
<div style="left:0px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">Root</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="0" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">0</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">&nbsp;</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="deoTK6LSqLMpyzvek" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="deoTK6LSqLMpyzvek" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">deoTK6LSqLMpyzvek</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="P1" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:36px;">
<div style="left:18px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">P1</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="1" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">1</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="utCQPQnEMSgWuMoWP" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">utCQPQnEMSgWuMoWP</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="anpmHh4pBdYXXsLET" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="anpmHh4pBdYXXsLET" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">anpmHh4pBdYXXsLET</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="P2" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:54px;">
<div style="left:36px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">P2</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="2" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">2</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="deoTK6LSqLMpyzvek" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">deoTK6LSqLMpyzvek</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="ijdKhWuu82wvNSFvb" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="ijdKhWuu82wvNSFvb" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">ijdKhWuu82wvNSFvb</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="P3" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:72px;">
<div style="left:54px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">P3</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="3" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">3</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="anpmHh4pBdYXXsLET" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">anpmHh4pBdYXXsLET</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="wgTenEngDLzN6xmzw" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="wgTenEngDLzN6xmzw" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">wgTenEngDLzN6xmzw</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="pasdflkajsdfasfasdfasddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:90px;">
<div style="left:72px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">pasdflkajsdfasfasdfasddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="4" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">4</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="ijdKhWuu82wvNSFvb" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">ijdKhWuu82wvNSFvb</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="YatYX4q7tZfFX2b93" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="YatYX4q7tZfFX2b93" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">YatYX4q7tZfFX2b93</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="psdfasdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:108px;">
<div style="left:90px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">psdfasdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="5" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">5</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="wgTenEngDLzN6xmzw" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">wgTenEngDLzN6xmzw</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="LCFkH6iQGzTR4sfr2" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="LCFkH6iQGzTR4sfr2" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">LCFkH6iQGzTR4sfr2</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfasdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:126px;">
<div style="left:108px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfasdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="6" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">6</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="YatYX4q7tZfFX2b93" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">YatYX4q7tZfFX2b93</td>
<tr role="row" id="R6RETffMsDgJvkgHD" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="R6RETffMsDgJvkgHD" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">R6RETffMsDgJvkgHD</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfasdasdff" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:144px;">
<div style="left:126px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfasdasdff</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="mcHRMKF44m22EQ2DW" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="mcHRMKF44m22EQ2DW" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">mcHRMKF44m22EQ2DW</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:162px;">
<div style="left:144px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="8" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">8</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="R6RETffMsDgJvkgHD" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">R6RETffMsDgJvkgHD</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="n8jLsJyLpDWuNaTgz" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="n8jLsJyLpDWuNaTgz" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">n8jLsJyLpDWuNaTgz</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfas" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:180px;">
<div style="left:162px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfas</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="9" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">9</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="mcHRMKF44m22EQ2DW" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">mcHRMKF44m22EQ2DW</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="3toHRw3R627ZrWAtR" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="3toHRw3R627ZrWAtR" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">3toHRw3R627ZrWAtR</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfsdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:198px;">
<div style="left:180px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfsdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="NDMpdmfiiuT3k9fKm" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="NDMpdmfiiuT3k9fKm" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">NDMpdmfiiuT3k9fKm</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfasdfasdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:216px;">
<div style="left:198px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfasdfasdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="MXcAvzvRzgtbigS76" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="MXcAvzvRzgtbigS76" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">MXcAvzvRzgtbigS76</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfasfsdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:234px;">
<div style="left:216px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfasfsdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="6FvjM7HJTRxrtoYWH" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="6FvjM7HJTRxrtoYWH" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">6FvjM7HJTRxrtoYWH</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="wertwert" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:252px;">
<div style="left:234px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">wertwert</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="74FqMNeBqpr68vASn" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="74FqMNeBqpr68vASn" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">74FqMNeBqpr68vASn</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="ertwertwert" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:270px;">
<div style="left:252px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">ertwertwert</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="14" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">14</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="6FvjM7HJTRxrtoYWH" aria-describedby="gridProject_parent">6FvjM7HJTRxrtoYWH</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="false" aria-describedby="gridProject_isLeaf">false</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_expanded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="ek3oYvow6PnfSD8iL" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="ek3oYvow6PnfSD8iL" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">ek3oYvow6PnfSD8iL</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="wertwertw" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:288px;">
<div style="left:270px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">wertwertw</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="15" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">15</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="dAqQomG4piLj8gxxc" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="dAqQomG4piLj8gxxc" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">dAqQomG4piLj8gxxc</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="wertwerert" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:306px;">
<div style="left:288px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">wertwerert</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="QD5s3zfygRXJupkN2" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="QD5s3zfygRXJupkN2" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">QD5s3zfygRXJupkN2</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="wertwertert" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:324px;">
<div style="left:306px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">wertwertert</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="17" aria-describedby="gridProject_level">17</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="WL38eyFzXSZbBZHXh" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="WL38eyFzXSZbBZHXh" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">WL38eyFzXSZbBZHXh</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="lksjdfoinasdflkasndf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:342px;">
<div style="left:324px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">lksjdfoinasdflkasndf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="8Qhm7AKZrqv3jWb2o" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="8Qhm7AKZrqv3jWb2o" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">8Qhm7AKZrqv3jWb2o</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="sdfasdfasdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:360px;">
<div style="left:342px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">sdfasdfasdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="yY4TWfdkaRunzHNCf" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="yY4TWfdkaRunzHNCf" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">yY4TWfdkaRunzHNCf</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfasdfasdf3245345" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:378px;">
<div style="left:360px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">asdfasdfasdf3245345</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="rMxya38hmYpM7ToBH" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="rMxya38hmYpM7ToBH" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">rMxya38hmYpM7ToBH</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="atasrt656456" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:396px;">
<div style="left:378px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">atasrt656456</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="YjzT5bgQYangqDaY9" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="YjzT5bgQYangqDaY9" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">YjzT5bgQYangqDaY9</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="t5werty3456456" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:414px;">
<div style="left:396px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">t5werty3456456</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="B2sHZ9NkfJgcXXPLn" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="B2sHZ9NkfJgcXXPLn" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">B2sHZ9NkfJgcXXPLn</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:432px;">
<div style="left:414px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-document-b tree-leaf treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapperleaf">asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="qw2hnFnbM3MwcqTgc" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="qw2hnFnbM3MwcqTgc" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">qw2hnFnbM3MwcqTgc</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="Q1" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:36px;">
<div style="left:18px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">Q1</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="ob6CCyYB8Qm4NaKTC" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="ob6CCyYB8Qm4NaKTC" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">ob6CCyYB8Qm4NaKTC</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="Q2" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:54px;">
<div style="left:36px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapper">Q2</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr role="row" id="eLC7xPkyQtdXweR3Q" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="eLC7xPkyQtdXweR3Q" aria-describedby="gridProject_id">eLC7xPkyQtdXweR3Q</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="Q3" aria-describedby="gridProject_Name">
<div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:72px;">
<div style="left:54px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-document-b tree-leaf treeclick"></div></div><span class="cell-wrapperleaf">Q3</span></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="true" aria-describedby="gridProject_loaded">true</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="gridProject_icon">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
<div class="ui-jqgrid-resize-mark" id="rs_mgridProject">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

Comment: You might not be able to post images but you can definitely post your code or maybe something like a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your issue. It will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: thanks Equalsk. I've added generated HTML.

Comment: Post your jqeury/Javascript code and NOT the generate html. Nobody is going to take a look into all this huge amount of code. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)